# Do effects like Shock and Burning still apply with Resolute Technique?

Tags: path-of-exile

I'm building an elemental cleave Templar and wondered whether effects like shock and burning will still proc if I go resolute technique. Will I still get the benefits after going resolute technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolute Technique does not make it that you cannot apply shock/ignite/freeze, but since you cannot crit, you cannot apply these effects using crit.
There are other ways to apply these effects though:

Items/Gear
Skill/Support gems (eg. Quality Added Cold Damage Support, Chance to Ignite Support, etc.)
Passive Tree Nodes (eg. Static Blows, Freeze, etc.)

Landing a critical strike with cold/fire/lightning damage automatically applies the effects, but you can also apply them using 'Chance to Freeze/Ignite/Shock'. Getting Resolute Technique stops the ability to apply the effects through crits.

On another note, unless you have decent accuracy rating, it may be better DPS to get resolute technique anyway.

Comment: Thanks, after doing a few tests I do more DPS without resolute technique than with. I can still switch in the future.